# jquery Ajax call only firing once

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Jquery Ajax call only fires once after that if i click on the button it does return the last returned reponse but doesn't go the ajax function in c#
Here is my aspx code

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="iBtnSaveUser" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm();" />
```

Here is my jquery Ajax function

```
    function ValidateForm() {
    if ($(txtName).val() == "") {
        alert('Name Required');
        return false;
    }
    else if ($(txtUserName).val() == "") {
        alert('UserName Required');
        return false;
    }
    else if ($(txtPassword).val() == "") {
        alert('Password Required');
        return false;
    }
    else if ($(txtEmail).val() == "") {
        alert('Email Required');
        return false;
    }
    else if ($(txtPhone).val() == "") {
        alert('Phone Number Required');
        return false;
    }
    else if ($(ddlProfile).val() == "") {
        alert('Profile Required');
        return false;
    }
    AddUser();
    return false;
}

    function AddUser() {
        var name = $(txtName).val();
        var userName = $(txtUserName).val();
        var password = $(txtPassword).val();
        var email = $(txtEmail).val();
        var phone = $(txtPhone).val();
        var profile = $(ddlProfile).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ajaxCallHandlerUrl,
            data: { OpCode: "AddUser", Params: "Name^" + name + "~UserName^" + userName + "~Email^" + email + "~Phone^" + phone + "~Profile^" + profile +"~Password^"+password },
            dataType: "",
            success: function (responseString) {
                alert(responseString);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try turning off caching:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    /* other params... */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

For the code that @Rory McCrossan entered didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```